# PHP if statement not working on all significant digits

Tags: php, if-statement, paypal

I have a custom shopping cart that has weights ranging from .05 to about 400 lbs. My shipping calculator only uses UPS, which would charge them accurately for all stuff we ship UPS. When we have only small items (which are also light), we ship USPS. To allow for this, I just put an if statement at the end of the UPS calculator:

```
if($weight>0 && $weight<5){            
  $handling='7.10';
}
```

Obviously my cart weight is stored as a session variable $weight, and my shipping charges are sent to paypal with the variable $handling.

This little if statement made it so that my web page ignored all UPS shipping charges between 1 pound and 5 pounds and just charged them $7.50 instead. This is exactly what I want, except I need it to work at anything from .01 to 5 lbs. Right now it is using the UPS rates from .01 to .99 lbs. I think it may be some kind of zero or significant digit error.

And my web site is strictly PHP and HTML. Please don't suggest anything Jquery/java/etc. And just so you know your audience, I am a self taught beginner coder :)

Thanks guys

Comment: I've read your question 10 times, I can't understand what you're asking. Where are you getting a significant digit error? Are you saying that when you send `7.10`, it's being sent as `7.50` instead?

Comment: Can you make maybe an example here: http://3v4l.org/mUT72 ?

Comment: No, I am saying that weights below 1 lb aren't being treated property. My shipping calculator has a buffer in it that pads shipping by a few percent to compensate for shipping claims and damage. The 7.10 turns into 7.50. Don't worry about the 7.10-7.50 thing. The problem is that the 7.10/7.50 number isn't being applied to cart weights below 1 pound.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that $weight isn't cast to integer at some point? When you var_dump($weight), do you get a float?
When cast to integer, 0.99 becomes 0 and that would not satisfy $weight > 0 condition. 
Also, string **0,99** might become 0.
EDIT: Just tested, '0.99' WILL become equal to zero when cast to integer (var_dump((int)'0.99');)

Comment: ...and that is exactly what your IF statement will do when comparing integer with string.

Comment: You are onto something Stormblack. I will start looking. And to Aldanux- I have over 500 lines of code in my cart, and it won't work outside my web page... so I don't think that is practical at this time.

Comment: Var_dump output is float(0.05). So it is not being stored as an integer. I also changed it to if($weight>0 && $weight<=5)
{            
    $handling=7.10;
}

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using string? Try this

```
if($weight>0 && $weight<=5)
{            
    $handling=7.10;
}
```

Comment: That took a few characters of code out of my web page, but didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't have negative weights, just use:

```
if( $weight < 5)
```

This should solve your problem.

The most likely cause of the problem in the first place is the weight being passed around as a string, I think.

Comment: I use zero weights for free shipping (so I need it to exclude 0). I will look further into the string thing.

Comment: I pulled the string tags off (double ')... no change. Does it affect anything where I am storing a session variable? like this? $_SESSION['weight'] = $weight;